# Does System.Timers.Timer terminates on aborting its working Thread?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, timer

I have these codes that use `System.Timers.Timer` on a method that called by a `Thread`:

```
private void timeWorker()
{
     var timer = new Timer(1000);
     timer.Enabled = true;
     timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
}
public MyConstructor()
{
    var thread=new Thread(timeWorker);
    thread.IsBackground = true;
    thread.Start();
    //
    thread.Abort();
}
```

Does `System.Timers.Timer` terminates on aborting its working Thread?

Comment: 1) Timer's don't really "belong" to the thread that created them. There's no relationship between the two. and 2) Whatever you're doing, `Thread.Abort` is almost certainly *not* the correct answer. But you haven't told us what *problem* you were attempting to solve here.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever My problem is that I want to ensure that by aborting thread, timer will no more be enabled.

Comment: But aborting a thread, in and of itself, is almost always **wrong**. Why do you believe that the best solution to your problem involves aborting a thread?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever so what's your suggestion? (I'm not so familiar with threads).

Comment: If all you want to do is to create a timer, and then at a later point stop that timer from running, just create the `Timer` object and store it in a field of your class. Then, at the later point when you want to stop it, set its `Enabled` property to `false`. I don't see why you create a `Thread` at all - the `Timer` object certainly doesn't need you to create one.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever indeed, I want to run a method which have timer in it, on several threads and then terminate some of threads (and that threads's timer).

Comment: Timers do not *belong* to a thread. I don't know where you got this misconception from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You cannot kill timer by aborting thread.
2. `Timer` has its own thread to invoke your event handler.
3. Also, as @Damien_The_Unbeliever said timer doesn't belong to any thread, it's system object.
4. `GC` will not collect timer because of your event handler.

You should use try-catch in your thread method implementation, to catch `ThreadAbortException` and stop timer.

Answer (score 0):

[MSDN C# Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/en-en/library/7a2f3ay4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

I suggest this link for general working with threads. It is also mentioned that `Abort` will interrupt the Thread and prevents used ressources to be cleaned up.

A better option would be a method to call that disables the while-loop inside the `timeWorker` Class like

```
public void RequestStop()
{
    running = false;
}
```

while the worker is doing his work in the loop

```
public void DoWork()
{
    while(running)
    {
        ...
    }
//execution stopped
}
```

with a variable `private volatile bool running`.