# Abort thread in Elapsed event

Tags: c#, multithreading, timer

Is there any need to abort timer thread in elapsed event? Or will `.net`  do it automatically? Here is my code:

```
private static void m_checker_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[threadid:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + "]");
    Thread.CurrentThread.Abort();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no need (and it could be harmful if it prevents resources from being unallocated). See the MSDN examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx), where they don't do so. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22856915/does-system-timers-timer-terminates-on-aborting-its-working-thread) asks a similar question, and it has some good points in the comments/answers (notably, that the thread the callback runs in is owned by the system).

If you're wanting to stop the timer, then just set its `Enabled` property to `false`, eg:

```
private static void m_checker_Elapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Foo");
    if (condition)
        (source as Timer).Enabled = false;
}
```